# OOM exception when generating a large array of strings

Tags: c#, asp.net, performance

I'm trying to generate a large amount of strings. In my small sample code it works as intended, but my desired result has a string length of 8, and not 3 like below, which results in an out of memory exception.

Is there any way to run this more efficiently?

```
string chars = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
string numbers = "0123456789";
var query = from c1 in chars 
            from c2 in chars 
            from d1 in digits 
            select string.Format("{0}{1}{2}", c1, c2, d1);
string[] possibleCombinations = query.ToArray();
```

Comment: Please do some basic Math, on number of combinations you are trying to generate. The number would probably be very large (billions or may be trillions).. and hence not sure what kind of solution you are looking for. Even if OOM problem was resolved, it would probably take a long time for you to enumerate so many values.. Why do you need so many strings generated in the first place?

Comment: Is your intent really to create a rainbow table of 218,340,105,584,896 entries (62^8) in memory?

Answer (score 0):

Don't call the `ToArray()` method! This causes the allocation of the memory. If you simply loop through the query an enumerator loops through all the possible results. You need to wait for a long time though to loop through all results.